Chrome Extension: Failed to copy image to clipboard and paste it into Google Image Translator
I'm developing a Chrome extension that allows users to right-click on an image, copy it to the clipboard, and automatically open a new tab with Google Image Translator, where the copied image should be pasted for translation. However, I'm encountering an issue where the image is not being copied to the clipboard correctly, and Google Image Translator displays an error message saying "Невозможно перевести файл этого формата" (Cannot translate a file of this format).
I've attempted various approaches to copy the image to the clipboard, including using the ClipboardItem API, creating a temporary img element, and using document.execCommand('copy'). However, none of these methods seem to work correctly. When I manually right-click on an image and select "Copy image" from the context menu, the image is copied and pasted into Google Image Translator without any issues.
I expected the image to be copied to the clipboard in a format compatible with Google Image Translator, but it seems that the copied image is not in the correct format.
I've been struggling with this issue for a while and have tried various approaches without success. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to correctly copy the image to the clipboard and ensure it can be pasted into Google Image Translator.
Here's the relevant code from my Chrome extension:
`// background.js

async function copyImageToClipboard(imageUrl) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const type = blob.type.split('/')[1] || 'png';
    const clipboardItem = new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob });
    await navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem]);
    console.log(`Image copied to clipboard as ${type}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to copy image to clipboard:', error);
  }
}`


navigator.clipboard doesn't work in invisible contexts. 1) You can try the deprecated document.execCommand (example) in the offscreen document. 2) Or use navigator.clipboard in the content script. 3) Or just supply the image blob directly to the site/service.
